# Why its Come [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am Creating UITableview and add Two UITableviewCell Custom Cells (ProductCell and DescripotionCell).I am displaying Data into UILabel. But I am Getting This Error ([__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance )and UITableviewCell not displaying Data. 
Please check my Code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;


    [self.detailedTableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];

    [self.detailedTableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DescriptionCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DescriptionCell"];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.detailedTableview])
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            return 396;
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            //  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
            return 100;

        }
           }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            return 396;
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            // return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
            return 100;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifierproduct = @"ProductCell";
    static NSString *cellIdentifierDescription = @"DescriptionCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        ProductCell *cellProduct =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierproduct];



        return cellProduct;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section ==1)
    {
        DescriptionCell *cellDes =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierDescription];

        NSString*urlString  = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"http://54.254.171.25/android/bnm/api/servicesAPI.php?request=getProductDetails&pid=1"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError *error;
       NSDictionary *dataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
       NSMutableArray *descArray =[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pd_description"];
         NSLog(@"%@",descArray);
         cellDes.descriptionLbl.text = [descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cellDes;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Please check

Comment: Why are you downloading data and parsing JSON in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? That needs to be done once and then the resulting data should be used as the table view's data source.

Comment: What does this line `NSLog(@"%@",descArray);` print immediately before the crash?

Comment: in descArray  printed this ( Linen Blend Material.
 Regular Collar.
 Full Sleeves.
 Slim Fit.
 Solid Pattern.
 Peach Color)

Comment: Please read something about the model-view-controller pattern. The **controller** loads the data into the **model** and updates the **view**. You're loading the data in the **view** which is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd_description` is a string. Remember that NSDictionary works with generic objects, or `id`. So the compiler does not see a problem when you are assigning an NSString into an NSArray. But on runtime, you are trying to call the methods of an Array from a String object, these methods do not exist in the NSString definition resulting in a `Unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

```
pd_description: "Linen Blend Material.
 Regular Collar.
 Full Sleeves.
 Slim Fit.
 Solid Pattern.
 Peach Color",
```

A way to fix this would be to get the string and separate its components.

```
NSString *pdDescription = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pd_description"];
NSMutableArray *descArray = [pdDescription componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSLog(@"%@",descArray);
         cellDes.descriptionLbl.text = [descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Update: Removing linebreaks**

```
NSString *pdDescription = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pd_description"];
pdDescription = [pdDescription stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n " withString:@""];
NSMutableArray *descArray = [pdDescription componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSLog(@"%@",descArray);
cellDes.descriptionLbl.text = [descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: but in my tableviewcell data not displaying. why its not displaying in UILabel.

Comment: That may be because of the line break, let me update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Desc array have one `indexpath`, so your code will crash. Try this code

```
cellDes.descriptionLbl.text = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pd_description"];
```